# How to create Re-Usable web control library

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, asp.net

**Question background:**
Hello everyone, I have been developing windows form application for my employer for about 3 years. Though most of my works are amateurish. I've been using visual studio, c#, enjoying creating re-usable windows form controls by sub-classing and other techniques. Now my boss want me to make website for this company, the first thinking in my mind is to create re-usable WEB controls just like windors form application.

**The methods I have tried**

1. **Web User Control**, At very first, I found visual studio support developer to create `Web User Control`, with file extension as *.ascx. I was very exciting to find this because I thought I can create Web controls just like I did in windows form application development. BUT, it's a very big "BUT", I then found that it cannot be embed to assembly file (DLL), and either can it be displayed in ToolBox to support drag and drop in web page design time. AFAIK from msdn, the `Web User Control` is not intended to be re-used across projects. So I give up this method.
2. **Server Control**, then I found there is `Custom Server Control` can be created to support assembly embed and ToolBox. It's a *.cs file that written with a class which sub-classing from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` or `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl`. Good point is that this is exactly what I want: re-usability and design-time support. HOWEVER, the huge disadvantage is that it doesn't support drag-drop when creating the web control itself. The control can only be rendered by html written in c# or be created by code. And I have to embed css/javascript to the control if I want to create more beautiful, complicated or efficient control. Anyway, from MSDN, `Server Control` is what I need.
3. **Pure HTML, Javascript (jQuery), CSS**, actually I've beening working with `Server Control` method for a while, just in order to make my boss happy. But I still cannot stop thinking about other better solutions. From my understanding, web page is not that complicated, it's simply constructed (please correct me if I'm wrong) by `HTML tag`, `javascript (or other scripting language)`, `CSS to manipulate UI`. So I believe if I create web control by pure Html, Javascript and CSS, it will be of course more complicated but more compatible. Because `Server Control` solution requires the web server support .Net Framework, which is not free and limited to Microsoft scope. If I have a way to get rid of .Net, why NOT? I'm willing to spend double-time to create Re-Usable control if it's worthy to do. For example, if I want to turn to PHP to create web page, I might have to acquire the technique to create my web control simply by HTML, Javascript and CSS.

**My question**

1. Speaking all of the above, is it even possible to create my web control library only based on Html, Javascript and CSS?
2. If so, is there any tutorial about this method?
3. I really would like to know that how does commercial/professional company create web page.

Thank you everyone, any advice will be very much appreciated!

Comment: look into existing ones like dojo, yui, jqui, extjs, etc. and make sure you know all the good stuff built-in to html5, like sliders, <datalist>, number/date/color inputs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. Speaking all of the above, is it even possible to create my web control library only based on Html, Javascript and CSS?

In strict speak, the controls you have become accustomed to support the aforementioned. This will continue work in future projects created in WebForms.

However, if you foray into MVC then there is a striking difference. Most of the controls that handle input are client side (which can be wrapped in js wigets and user validation classes). On the other hand there is very little server controls, however there are _MasterLayouts and Views that can make use of PartialViews a **PartialView** is similar to a **Web User Control**. In your **Controller** you can return EditTemplates and other types that would be similar to **Server Controls**

Answer (score 0):

After digging for a few days, I almost give up creating my own javascript library not just only for web widget(UI), neither I would like to use third-part js frameworks because:

1. Cost too much time: as it says: 'do not reinvent the wheel', well, I accept/disagree with this point half by half. But now, I simply do not have too much time on it. It really really cost time, can hardly complish by an individual person.
2. A lot javascript frameworks are so great, like dojo, yui, jqui, as @dandavis commented, BUT, the usage of some is difficult, at least for me (as a js beginner), especially dojo. Dojo is very powerful, AFAIK, but it's hard to implement and use. I followed official tutorial to create my own web widget, spend a hour and not get it done. I might give up too fast?
3. I still want to dig asp.net **with ajax**, it is much powerful. And can easily manipulate on server side.

Well, I don't know if it's an answer but this is my personal end of my question. Thanks a lot guys.